# saving predicted image in python make it much darker

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am doing a job in which my CNN will predict an image.
the image passed to the model is normalized using min max technique.
the problem is, when displaying the predicted image with matplotlib, I got a beautiful brigtned image. But when saving the image using openCV for example, the image become darker.
the problem is that I want to save the beautiful one with the size of the darker one (because with opencv the image will keep the original size, but with savefig the image saved is a figure ).
here, I show you the difference between them !

> ps: I tried to multiply the predicted one by 255.0 // I tried also to implement a denormalization technique, but unfortunately I got the sama image !!

code used for normalization:

```
def normalize(data):
  data_new = data.astype(np.float32)
  return (data_new - np.min(data_new))/(np.max(data_new) - np.min(data_new))
```

code used for predicting/saving (minimal):

```
prediction = mainModel.predict(img_g)
prediction = np.squeeze(prediction, axis=0)
f, a = plt.subplots(1, 1,figsize=(2.5,2.5))
imageio.imwrite('/content/output.jpg',prediction*255.0)
a.imshow(prediction)
plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False) #not important
plt.gca().axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False) #not important
plt.savefig('/content/frame.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: saved using matplotlib savefig]
[image: saved using openCV]